# Replace values in Pandas DataFrame with value based on headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Pandas DataFrame

```
Index 1  2  3  4  5
    0 1  1  0  0  0
```

I want to replace it:

```
Index 1     2
    0 pos1  pos2
```

*I have seen a similar question but use "ix", deprecated solutions or only replace values with headers*

Comment: Can you explain the replacement rule a bit more clearly?  What if the `5` column has a `1`?  Are values only `0` or `1`?  If it's a data frame, it'd be better to provide more than one row of example data and show the expected output for multiple rows.

Comment: If column 5 has a one then a third column with pos5

Comment: This is subset of a data frame so it's always only one line

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `replace` and `add_prefix`:

```
df.replace({k: 1 for k in df.columns}, 
           {k: v for k, v in zip(df.columns, df.add_prefix('pos').columns.values)})
```

Alternately, you can use `apply` and replace `1` values with `pos` + `.name` property of that entry (which is equivalent to the column name in this case):

```
df.apply(lambda row: [f"pos{row.name}" if x == 1 else x for x in row], axis=0)
```

Output (for both approaches):

```
          1     2  3  4  5
Index                     
0      pos1  pos2  0  0  0
```

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0}]).rename_axis('Index')
```